# Grails GORM date databinding

Tags: grails, data-binding, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I am using Grails 2.3 and I have a domain with a date field:

```
class DomainClass {
    String title
    Date datetime
}
```

And I have a json coming in to the RestfulController with timestamp in milliseconds:

```
{"title": "name", "datetime": 957044075522}
```

The controller is binding the title correctly but for the datetime field, it is actually an error:

```
Could not find matching constructor for: java.util.Date(com.google.gson.internal.LazilyParsedNumber)
```

What's the best way to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: You might need to pass it as string with in a date format or implement custom data binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the Brain F and zoran119 answers make sense so I voted them up. If anyone is doing the same thing, this is the actual answer that works:

```
@BindUsing({ obj, source -> source['datetime']?.longValue() })
Date datetime
```

Comment: I hadn't know of the BindUsing annotation so thanks for educating me, really elegant solution! Have voted up accordingly. Just curious how you cater for possible junk such as letters being sent in the datetime field?

Answer (score 2):

I would try using `@BindingFormat` annotation:

```
import org.grails.databinding.BindingFormat

class DomainClass {
    String title
    @BindingFormat('MMddyyyy')
    Date datetime
}
```

You need to replace `MMddyyyy` to something which will work for you...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against sending milliseconds as you are losing the timezone information.

If that's not an issue for you and want to go ahead as is I would just recommend using a command object in your controller which parses it as a string and then do a custom binding.

```
class DomainCmd {
   String title
   String datetime

   static constraints = {
       datetime matches: /[0-9]{12}/
   } 
}
```

Then in the controller;

```
myControllerAction(DomainCmd cmd) {
   if (cmd.validate()) {
       def myDomain = new DomainClass(title: cmd.title, datetime: new Date(cmd.datetime))
       // 
   } else {
      // HTTP ERROR 
      response.status = 400
   }
}
```

(also consider using joda time instead of java dates)